# Variadic template error: 'In instantiation of' (gcc 9.2)

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, variadic-templates, deduction-guide

I'm learning about variadic template on c++17 on the Jason Turner's [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gNzhE-Tn40&list=PLs3KjaCtOwSZ2tbuV1hx8Xz-rFZTan2J1&index=50) then I copy his example code (shown below). In his video he uses the site [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) with the gcc 7.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename ... B>
struct Merged : B ... {
       template<typename ... T>
       Merged(T&& ... t) : B(std::forward<T>(t))... {}

    using B::operator()...;
};

template<typename ... T>
Merged(T...) -> Merged<std::decay_t<T>...>;

int main() {
    const auto l1 = []() { return 4; };
    const auto l2 = [](const int i) { return i * 10; };

    Merged merged(l1,
                  l2,
                  [](const double d) { return d * 3.2; });

    return 0;
}
```

I tried the code in my computer with the gcc 9.2 and I got the follow error:

> In instantiation of 'Merged::Merged(T&& ...) (with T = {const main()::&, const main()::&, main()::}; B = {}]':

I tried to use the godbolt site to check it out but it also doesn't compile (with gcc 7.1 and gcc 9.2) and give more errors like:

> error: missing template arguments before 'merged'Merged merged(l1,

and

> error: expected primary-expression before ')' token [](const double d) { return d * 3.2; });

What this error means and what I need to do do fix it?

*Compile line in my computer:*

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -O2 -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -std=c++1z -m64  -c /home/thearquitect/Desktop/C++/variadic.cpp -o ~/Desktop/obj/variadic.o
g++ -o ~/Desktop/bin/variadic ~/Desktop/obj/variadic.o -s -m64
```

[godbolt try](https://godbolt.org/z/GGBdzZ)

Comment: `In instantiation of ...` is not a complete error message. `missing template arguments before 'merged'` means you forgot `-std=c++17`. After adding the missing flag, I get this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rXjgGp For some reason GCC deduces `B` as an empty list, ignoring the deduction guide. The same code works in Clang, so it looks like a GCC bug.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that strange because I used this flag... (I edited the question to show it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What this error means and what I need to do do fix it?

Nothing wrong in your code, as far I understand.

I suspect a g++ bug.

To fix it... well... to go around it... don't ask me why but I see that works, for both compilers, require a first template parameter, before the variadic list, for `Merged`.

I mean: the following `struct`

```
template <typename B0, typename ... B>
struct Merged : public B0, public B ...
 {
   template <typename T0, typename ... T>
   Merged (T0 && t0, T && ... t)
      : B0{std::forward<T0>(t0)}, B{std::forward<T>(t)}...
    { }

   using B0::operator();
   using B::operator()...;
};
```

together with the following deduction guide

```
template <typename T0, typename ... T>
Merged (T0, T ...) 
   -> Merged<std::decay_t<T0>, std::decay_t<T>...>;
```

works with both compilers.

Also your original deduction guide works with the modified `struct`.

**-- EDIT --**

I see that you can also solve the problem (compiling with both compilers) maintaining the `struct` with only the variadic list

```
template <typename ... B>
struct Merged: public B ...
 {
   template <typename ... T>
   Merged (T && ... t)
      : B{std::forward<T>(t)}...
    { }

   using B::operator()...;
};
```

and using a deduction guide with a required argument

```
template <typename T0, typename ... T>
Merged (T0, T ...) 
   -> Merged<std::decay_t<T0>, std::decay_t<T>...>;
```

Comment: That help me a lot! The main problem then is in the deduction guide (DG) on gcc. In fact it needs both DGs (not a replacement) because with just your DG I can't instantiate Merged with just one parameter.